# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dispatchers.Main is used concurrently with setting it Crash during instrumentation tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, android-instrumentation

I've been trying to nail down a particularly nasty crash during my tests that occur when setting up/using `Dispatchers.Main` value.  I see this issue about once every 10 or so runs.

Example stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dispatchers.Main is used concurrently with setting it
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcher$NonConcurrentlyModifiable.concurrentRW(TestMainDispatcher.kt:71)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcher$NonConcurrentlyModifiable.setValue(TestMainDispatcher.kt:89)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcher.setDispatcher(TestMainDispatcher.kt:36)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestDispatchers.setMain(TestDispatchers.kt:24)
at com.zao.testcommon.CoroutineTestRule.starting(CoroutineTestRule.kt:20)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.startingQuietly(TestWatcher.java:113)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.access$000(TestWatcher.java:52)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:59)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:67)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:446)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2205)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: reader location
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcher$NonConcurrentlyModifiable.getValue(TestMainDispatcher.kt:75)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcher.dispatch(TestMainDispatcher.kt:29)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:320)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith$default(DispatchedContinuation.kt:276)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.ScopeCoroutine.afterCompletion(Scopes.kt:27)
at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.continueCompleting(JobSupport.kt:939)
at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.access$continueCompleting(JobSupport.kt:25)
at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport$ChildCompletion.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1158)
at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCompletion(JobSupport.kt:1494)
at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.completeStateFinalization(JobSupport.kt:324)
at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.finalizeFinishingState(JobSupport.kt:241)
at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompletingSlowPath(JobSupport.kt:909)
at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompleting(JobSupport.kt:866)
at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCompletingOnce$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:831)
at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.resumeWith(AbstractCoroutine.kt:100)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I use a standard `CoroutineTestRule`:

```
class CoroutineTestRule : TestWatcher() {
    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        super.starting(description)

        val testDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        super.finished(description)

        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

And each test sets this up via:

```
    @get:Rule
    val coroutineTestRule = CoroutineTestRule()
```

In the stacktrace when the crash occurs, I see that the `CoroutineTestRule` is one of the two places that are accessing the `Dispatchers.Main`.  *A* test (not sure which?) is starting, and we need to setup the dispatchers... but I can't seem to figure out the second thread that is using the `Dispatchers.Main` value... it seems related to a coroutine resuming (from `BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith` and other methods named here), but I can't understand why...

My instrumentation tests use a combination of activity/fragment scenarios, etc. (all standard practice stuff), but shouldn't these all "die down" by the time the next test is starting?

Comment: same problem here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solve for this was simple, but time consuming.

I have multiple modules in my app, and while tests running with a given module are synchronous, multiple modules can be running tests at the same time.

`Dispatchers.setMain` / `Dispatchers.resetMain` works on a singleton... so when you are running multiple module tests at once, there's a chance the test dispatcher could be set while it's currently being used as the error points out.

To fix this, you simply *cannot* use the test dispatcher APIs like this.  This means you cannot use `viewModelScope` which is bound to `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`, and instead need to create a custom coroutine scope for your viewmodel classes (and everything else hard coded against `Dispatchers.Main`.

It's relatively easy to do this - but just time consuming and unfortunate that the test APIs are setup like this... :sigh: